# Why is this output wrong ? - Sequential Consistency

Tags: distributed-computing, sequential, distributed-system

The way I understand sequential consistency model the output marked as wrong should be valid, what am I missing ?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take a look on the [definition of sequential consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency) in the wiki we'll see:

> the result of any execution is the same as if the operations of all the processors were executed in some sequential order, and **the operations of each individual processor appear in this sequence in the order specified by its program**

In your example the order of the P2 process is violated since the `print (x,z)` operation precedes `y=1`.